# I want to update this green box row's Quantity column value 200 to 100.. how to do it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is `tblSales` table. It contains two rows with same values.. I want to update this green box row.. please help me.. I'm a beginner to SQL Server.

[image]

A partial view of the table, from the above image:

```
CustID   SalesDate    ItemId    Quantity   Amount
---------------------------------------------------
C1       2009-01-01   ABC       100        1000.00
C2       2009-01-01   ABC       200        2000.00
C4       2009-12-01   PQR       200        2000.00
C4       2009-12-01   PQR       200        2000.00   <---- this one!
C2       2009-01-04   XYZ       500        NULL
C1       2009-01-05   XYZ       NULL       500.00
```

Comment: Off topic; if the two rows are identical then your table is called a [HEAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213609.aspx).  There are many reasons to avoid heaps and just a few reasons for using them.  If you haven't already can I recommend you read this article from the [SQL Server docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213609.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> On your object explorer :
> expand your Database, then expand tables, then right click on your table >and choose 'edit top 200 rows'.
>
> then edit and save it.

if you want to use query, you could use RN

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY CustID)
   FROM tblSales
)
UPDATE CTE set Quantity='100' WHERE RN=2 and CustID='C4';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't see the whole table, I'm not sure if this will work, but . . .

Your records probably have a unique identifier (ID, Primary Key, etc) - and it looks from your image that the duplicated rows have a unique (or at least different) value in the field to the left (partly cut off in the picture). Let's say that the rows have sequential IDs from 1-6. If so, then you can do a simple UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE tblSales
SET column_name = new_value, column_name2 = new_value . . .
WHERE ID = 4;
```

In this case, specifying the changes you want to make - for example, to change the quantity of the fourth row:

```
UPDATE tblSales
SET quantity = 100
WHERE ID = 4;
```

if the ID in that column isn't unique, it's still different from the row above, so you can do:

```
UPDATE tblSales
SET quantity = 100
WHERE id = 4 AND CustID = 'C4' and ItemID = 'PQR';
```

the multiple WHERE will uniquely identify the row in that case (you can run it as a SELECT query first to ensure that it identifies only one row before going ahead with an UPDATE)

if there's NO unique identifier and these are true duplicate rows, I refer you to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139444

Comment: i guess that its not an primary key. its just a row number from the Management Studio itself. Thats why i think that query wont work in this case.

Comment: i just think that OP doesnt have ID in his table structure. only CustID as we see it. but im not sure, lets wait for OP confirmation.